# Spanning Theory of Linear Algebra

Tags: linear-algebra

I am not really sure how we can decide that some linearly independent set spans $\mathbb R^n$? Can you explain what are the criteria when we say it spans $\mathbb R^n$?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  A set spans $\mathbb R^n$ if any element of $\mathbb R^n$ can be expressed as a linear combination of its elements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it spans a space, then the elements of that space can be written as the linear combination of its elements.

Lets assume that $<1,2>,<3,4>$ are two vector. If we can the values of $c_1,c_2$ in terms of $a,b$ when we wrote it in the form of $c_1<1,2>+c_2<3,4>=<a,b>$ ,then it spans the space.

In other words, when you write a linear equation in the form of augmented matrix, if you have infinity many solutions then it spans the space.

When we comes to your question , if we cannot find $b$ in the system of $Ax=b$, then it does not span the space

Comment: So, lets call a basis with b1.....bp. Then when we are trying to show that this basis spans Rn, we can easily check Ax=b with fixed b.

The problem is that when there is no fixed b.

Comment: @amdryzen7000 if $b_1,..b_p$ are the basis of the space ,then they are linearly independent and spanning .Did it help you?

Comment: Actually after writing that, I regret because spanning is condition for basis. What I tried to ask, for a set which doesn't have to be basis, how I can be sure that it spans or not? 

Sorry If I ask too much, I don't want to waste your time.

Comment: oh, ı understood, wait a couple minute , it will take time to write.I am writing it for you

Comment: @amdryzen7000 is it okay now ?

Comment: Yes, it is crystal clear for me now. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1):

A "spanning set" or "a set that spans the vector space" is a set such that any member of the vector space can be written as a linear combination of vectors in the set.

A spanning set is NOT necessarily a basis.  A basis is a set that both spans the vector space AND such that the vectors in the set are linearly independent.  It easy to see that a set consisting of a single (non-zero) vector is linearly independent but probably wont span the space!  As we add more vectors to the set they are less likely to be independent but more likely to span the space.  On the other hand, the set of all vectors certainly spans the space but can't be linearly independent.  As we remove vectors from the set they become more likely to be independent but less likely to span the space.

In Linear Algebra, dealing with finite dimensional vector spaces, there is one number, n, where they "meet in the middle".  That is, there exist a set of vectors that both spans the space and is linearly independent.  That set is a basis for the space and the specific number "n" is the "dimension" of the vector space.